# Hibernate creates new row on save and not updates

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am using MySQL + spring + hibernate.

When I execute the following code it creates a new row:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .save(configTable);
```

However this code below updates

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .update(configTable);
```

I am not sure why the above code creates a new row in tables it should update in both cases to my understanding,
Any idea what could I be missing? Or what info will you need to help me track the problem...

Comment: `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .update(configTable);` creates new row?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **saveOrUpdate()** session method as:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(configTable);
```

Answer (score 1):

When update pass Entity primary key for update.

Make sure that your Entity have this annotation for save and update.

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicInsert = true, dynamicUpdate = true)
```